# Initializing std::string embedded in std::pair with non-1-argument ctor?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, constructor, std-pair

Is it possible to construct a std::pair if I want to construct the embedded std::string with a constructor that takes more than 1 argument?

E.g., this is legal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::pair<int, int> pair(2, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

...and this is legal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::pair<int, std::string> pair(2, "hello");
  return 0;
}
```

...but I wonder if something like the following is possible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::pair<int, std::string> pair{2, {"hello", 3}}; //Unclear if some variation/combination of parentheses and curly braces can make this legal.
  return 0;
}
```

I *think* the above is correct syntax to use "uniform initializer lists", but this won't work for my purposes because I'm using a pre-C++11 compiler. Is there some way to pull this off with pre-C++11 syntax?

To clarify, I'm trying to use this std::string constructor:

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              size_type count,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

As context on why I'm asking this, this is for academic curiosity (correct me if wrong): I think doing one-line construction like this is more efficient because the `std::pair` and its members are simply created and initialized all in one go. Whereas if I did something like this (using C++11 syntax)...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::pair<int, int> pair(2, 3);
  std::pair<int, std::string> pair2 = {2, {"hello", 3}};
  return 0;
}
```

...then I'm technically creating a `std::pair<int, std::string>` whose members are default-contructed, followed by invoking `std::pair`'s `operator=`, followed by invoking the `operator=` on the pair's members.

Comment: `std::string("hello",3)`? Which constructor are you trying to use and why?

Comment: @c650: Updated post to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write:

```
std::pair<int, std::string> pair( 2, std::string( "hello", 3 ) );
```

As for this declaration:

```
std::pair<int, std::string> pair2 = {2, {"hello", 3}};
```

then in fact it is equivalent to this declaration:

```
std::pair<int, std::string> pair{2, { "hello", 3}};
```

due to the copy constructor elision. Take into account that there is neither assignment operator because it is a declaration.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    struct Pair
    {
        std::string s;
        int i;
        Pair(int i, const std::string &s) : i(i), s(s)
        {
            std::cout << "Pair( int, std::string )" << std::endl;
        }

        Pair( const Pair &p) : i(p.i), s(p.s)
        {
            std::cout << "Pair( const Pair & )" << std::endl;
        }
    };

    Pair p1{ 2, { "hello", 3 } };
    Pair p2 = { 2, { "hello", 3 } };
}
```

The program output is:

```
Pair( int, std::string )
Pair( int, std::string )
```

Comment: I guess this answers my question, but I'm still curious: is it possible with pre-C++11 syntax without using an intermediate std::string object?

Comment: @StoneThrow No, it is impossible.

Comment: So, Vlad, using C++11 syntax, due to copy elision, the two methods of constructing the Pair are equal efficiency, right? I.e. my assumption about the default-construction followed by multiple invocations of `operator=` is not true, right?

Comment: @StoneThrow There is neither assignment operator. When objects are created using other objects then there are used constructors: either the copy constructor or the move constructor. To make the copy elision would be valid the copy/move constructor must be accessible though it is not called.

Comment: The second and third form are not equivalent "due to the copy constructor elision". There's no copy to elide. Copy-list-initialization doesn't (even notionally) create a temporary, unlike its non-list counterpart.